# Error in initializing Postgres in Manjaro Linux system

Tags: postgresql, manjaro

Here's the step by step commands i applied. I cant seem to start the Postgre database. Any ideas?

step 1:

```
 sudo pacman -S postgresql vim
```

step 2:

```
postgres --version
postgres (PostgreSQL) 16.1
```

step 3:

```
echo "en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8" | sudo tee /etc/locale.gen
en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8
➜  ~ sudo locale-gen
Generating locales...
  en_US.UTF-8... done
Generation complete.
```

step 4:

```
systemctl status postgresql
× postgresql.service - PostgreSQL database server
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enab>
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2023-12-28 11:53:39>
        CPU: 26ms

Starting PostgreSQL database server...
Dec 28 12:02:15 user postgres[4890]: "/var/lib/postgres/data" is missing or empty. Use a command like
Dec 28 12:02:15 user postgres[4890]:   su - postgres -c "initdb --locale en_US.UTF-8 -D '/var/lib/postgres/data'"
Dec 28 12:02:15 user postgres[4890]: with relevant options, to initialize the database cluster.
Dec 28 12:02:15 user systemd[1]: postgresql.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Dec 28 12:02:15 user systemd[1]: postgresql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 28 12:02:15 user systemd[1]: Failed to start PostgreSQL database server.
```

Comment: It is telling you the command to run. Did you bother trying it?

Comment: I ran  su - postgres -c "initdb --locale en_US.UTF-8 -D '/var/lib/postgres/data', it just switched to dquote>, what do I do next? I tried running the step 4 command, but "dquote" returned nothing

Comment: You missed the trailing `"`.

Comment: sudo pacman -S postgresql
[sudo] password for postgres: 
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for postgres: 
postgres is not in the sudoers file.

Comment: You need to start helping yourself. Either add the postgres user to the suoders list, or change its password, su to it, then run the command that way.